# Разделяй и властвуй/динамическое программирование: подмассив с суммой, близкой к нулю

Tags: c#, массивы, алгоритм

Надо найти решение данной задачи за O(n) или O(nlogn). Алгоритм Кадана не работает, даже если искать минимальную по модулю сумму, разделяй и властвуй тоже сыпется. Ниже приведен написанный мною код.

```
private double Calculate(int left, int right, out int start, out int finish)
{
    if (right == left)
    {
        start = left;
        finish = left;
        return arr[left];
    }
    int s1 = left, f1 = right, s2, f2, s3, f3;
    int middle = (left + right) / 2;
    double leftmin = double.MaxValue;
    double rightmin = double.MaxValue;
    double temp = 0;
    for (int i = middle; i >= left; i--)
    {
        temp += arr[i];
        if (Math.Abs(temp) < Math.Abs(leftmin))
        {
            leftmin = temp;
            s1 = i;
        }
    }
    temp = 0;
    for (int i = middle + 1; i <= right; i++)
    {
        temp += arr[i];
        if (Math.Abs(temp) < Math.Abs(rightmin))
        {
            rightmin = temp;
            f1 = i;
        }
    }
    double leftans = Calculate(left, middle, out s2, out f2);
    double rightans = Calculate(middle + 1, right, out s3, out f3);

    double res =  MinByAbs(MinByAbs(leftans, rightans), leftmin + rightmin);
    if (res == leftans)
    {
        start = s2;
        finish = f2;
    }
    else if (res == rightans)
    {
        start = s3;
        finish = f3;
    }
    else
    {
        start = s1;
        finish = f1;
    }
    return res;
}

private double MinByAbs(double a, double b)
{
    if (Math.Abs(a) < Math.Abs(b))
        return a;
    return b;
}
```

arr - массив в классе. Например, код не работает, если массив - {5, 6, -5, -6}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строим ряд частичных сумм от нулевого до i-го элемента - O(n).
Наша задача - найти две одинаковые суммы (или максимально близкие).
Сортируем (с запоминанием номеров в исходных позициях) - O(n log n).
Теперь проходим по отсортированному массиву, находя минимальную разность (или два одинаковых элемента) - еще O(n).

Итого - алгоритм O(n log n) - это же вроде годится?

Набросок на C++ (C#, увы, не знаю):

```
vector<int> seq = { 5, 6, -5, -6, 2, 4 };

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<pair<int,int>> sum(seq.size());
    sum[0] = make_pair(seq[0],0);
    for(int i = 1; i < seq.size(); ++i)
        sum[i] = make_pair(sum[i-1].first+seq[i],i);

    sort(sum.begin(),sum.end());

    int min = numeric_limits<int>::max(), idx = 0;
    // Тут приходится добавлять обработку нулевого индекса и нулевого значения...
    for(int i = 0; i < sum.size(); ++i)
    {
        int diff = abs(sum[i].first-((i == 0) ? 0 : sum[i-1].first));
        if (diff < min)
        {
            min = diff;
            idx = i;
        }
    }
    cout << "min sum = " << min << " between [" << ((idx == 0) ? 0 : sum[idx-1].second+1)
        << "] and [" << sum[idx].second << "]\n";

}
```

Comment: А почему - в порядке бреда?

Comment: Ну, пока не проверил реально кодом... :)